# Redis-3 Cluster. Master Cluster Info Down and Slave Cluster info Ok

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

**Setup:**

1. Master = 3
2. Slaves = 5

**Example:**

*Master*

1. 121.244.255.107:6380
2. 121.244.255.108:6379
3. 121.244.255.109:6379

*Slaves*

1. 115.114.79.37:6379
2. 115.114.79.38:6379
3. 115.114.79.39:6380
4. 115.114.79.40:6379
5. 115.114.79.41:6379

**Script to setup Cluster**

```
#!/bin/sh
redis_cli="redis-cli"
ping="ping"
cluster="CLUSTER"
cluster_reset="$cluster RESET"
cluster_reset_hard="$cluster_reset hard"
cluster_meet="$cluster MEET"
cluster_info="$cluster INFO"
cluster_nodes="$cluster NODES"
cat redis-cluster-hosts.txt | sed -e "s/:/ /" | while read ip port
    do
        echo $ip $port
        retval=("$redis_cli -h $ip -p $port $ping")
        $retval
        echo "CLUSTER RESET"
        $redis_cli -h $ip -p $port $cluster_reset
        cat redis-cluster-hosts.txt | sed -e "s/:/ /" | while read ip1 port1
        do
             echo "MEET"
             $redis_cli -h $ip -p $port $cluster_meet $ip1 $port1
        done
        echo "INFO"
        $redis_cli -h $ip -p $port $cluster_info
        $redis_cli -h $ip -p $port $cluster_nodes
    done
echo "Handshake Complete"
## First Time only 
## set up the solts
for i in {0..5461}; do redis-cli -h 121.244.255.107 -p 6380 cluster addslots ${i}; done
for i in {5462..10922}; do redis-cli -h 121.244.255.108 -p 6379 cluster addslots ${i}; done
for i in {10922..16383}; do redis-cli -h 121.244.255.109 -p 6379 cluster addslots ${i}; done
```

**Status of Masters: CLUSTER NODES**
All Masters

Master 1:

```
NODE-ID-1 121.244.255.107:6380 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected 10922-16383
```

Nothing about other nodes, masters or slaves

**Status of Slaves: CLUSTER NODES**

All Slaves 
Slave 1:

```
NODE-ID-MASTER-3 121.244.255.109:6379 master - 0 1442046644622 0 connected 10922-16383
NODE-ID-MASTER-2 121.244.255.108:6379 master - 0 1442046645627 0 connected 5462-10921
NODE-ID-SLAVE-1  115.114.79.38:6379   slave NODE-ID-MASTER-2 0 1442046646127 3 connected
NODE-ID-SLAVE-2  115.114.79.39:6380   slave NODE-ID-MASTER-2 0 1442046645122 1 connected
NODE-ID-SLAVE-3  115.114.79.41:6379   slave NODE-ID-MASTER-1 0 1442046645122 2 connected
NODE-ID-SLAVE-4  115.114.79.40:6379   myself,slave NODE-ID-MASTER-3 0 0 4 connected
NODE-ID-MASTER-1 121.244.255.107:6380 master - 0 1442046645627 0 connected 0-5461
NODE-ID-SLAVE-5  115.114.79.37:6379   slave NODE-ID-MASTER-3 0 1442046646127 0 connected
```

all the information about other nodes, masters and slaves

**Status of Masters: CLUSTER INFO**

```
cluster_state:fail
cluster_slots_assigned:5461
cluster_slots_ok:5461
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:1
cluster_size:1
cluster_current_epoch:0
cluster_my_epoch:0
cluster_stats_messages_sent:136176
cluster_stats_messages_received:136176
```

Cluster fails for MASTERS

**Status of Slaves: CLUSTER INFO**

```
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:8
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:4
cluster_my_epoch:0
cluster_stats_messages_sent:298888
cluster_stats_messages_received:298790
```

Cluster is running on slaves

How come cluster seems on on SLAVES and not on MASTERS.

ON `set foo 1` error is coming on MASTERS `(error) CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down`

On `set foo 1` error is coming on SLAVES (expected) `(error) MOVED 12182 121.244.255.109:6379`

What am I missing here ?

1. Handshake completed
2. Replicate slaves
3. redis config has cluster enabled

What is missing ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @rick , no i am not able to understand the issue here. instead of cluster, we are now relying on sentinel